# Configure Intellij's "New Project" defauts to use Spring MVC version 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a Spring MVC application with Spring v5, using the Intellij default settings, under "new project" > spring > spring MVC. However, it seems to be using Spring `4.3.18.Release` as the Spring version.

This is the main window that starts up when I select "Spring" from the options on the left, with `4.3.18.Release` pre-selected -

[image]

There seems to be an option at the end to "Configure" which release of Spring is selected, but the next screen has just Spring 4.3.18 and 3.2.18 as the available options -

[image]

How do I configure the settings to use the latest Spring ([5.1.4.Release](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core)) instead?

Answer (score 1):

Click on **"Spring Initializr"** instead of **"Spring"**
and the power of Spring is with you.

Answer (score 0):

This way of creating projects is considered obsolete, please consider using dedicated build tool like Maven/Gradle and/or https://spring.io/guides sample projects to create new projects: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198984

If you need to use that wizard the only way is to manually download the Spring 5 libraries and then go to Create new Spring project and add this newly downloaded directory to be used in the project.